# How to use Progress bar such that it progress depends on the progress of a specified method?

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, user-interface, ubuntu

I am developing a GUI project which contains a **Method** for performing mysql query, connecting to various SSH Server and accessing files, say **Method: M1**.
Whenever I call method **M1** my GUI Current Dialog becomes unresponsive till the method **M1** get completed(as **M1** is very expensive method).


Now instead of showing an unresponsive Dialog, I want to use a progress bar which will reflect the progress of method **M1**. There must be some way to do the same, is there?
I am using Java Swing package for developing the GUI.

Comment: First I would suggest you take a look at [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) and [Worker Threads and SwingWorker](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html).  To answer the question, you don't.  What you do is focus on returning a progress value of 0-1 (or 0-100) instead, this way, the UI just doesn't care

Comment: MadProgrammer, great i'll look into it.